# Application Language Change depending on which button is click

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-animation

I want to change my app language depending on 2 buttons. The problem is that when i select button language i want to restart activity animations and changes app language. The language changes but the animation is not working and some text are not shown.

```
 al = (Button)findViewById(R.id.al);
al.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            locale = new Locale("al");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            LanguageActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_language);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try recreating the activity instead of resetting the content view :

```
LanguageActivity.this.recreate();
```

**Edit**

> When button language is pressed i want to recreate the same activity and after few seconds to open new activity

To start another activity after few seconds use this :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // 3 seconds before starting a new activity
        final int millisBeforeStart = 3000;

        final Intent intent = new Intent(LanguageActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
     }
}, millisBeforeStart);
```

Comment: What about after recreate in selected language start new activity?

Comment: If you start an activity after changing the `locale`, the changes will be reflected in the new activity.

Comment: When button language is pressed  i want to recreate the same activity and after few seconds to open new activity